# gradle bootRun fails to run but runs successfully in IntelliJ

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I have a spring boot project on gradle 6, java 11. The project runs successfully in IntelliJ IDE. However when I try to run via gradle bootRun. I run into a weird error. A class from dependent project is somehow getting in the way of the project. Below is the error message I am seeing. I see similar errors others have reported with no clear resolution. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
2020-08-01 02:29:41.842  INFO 5990 --- [           main] c.t.i.cloud.saga.hotel.HotelApplication  : Starting HotelApplication on sseshac-in-la02.local with PID 5990 (/Users/sseshac/src/saga_demo/hotel/build/classes/java/main started by sseshac in /Users/sseshac/src/saga_demo/hotel)
2020-08-01 02:29:41.847  INFO 5990 --- [           main] c.t.i.cloud.saga.hotel.HotelApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-08-01 02:29:42.015  WARN 5990 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.demo.iec.cloud.saga.hotel.HotelApplication]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/demo/iec/cloud/saga/SagaCommandListener.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
2020-08-01 02:29:42.039 ERROR 5990 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.demo.iec.cloud.saga.hotel.HotelApplication]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/demo/iec/cloud/saga/SagaCommandListener.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:188) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:319) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:280) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:96) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:707) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:533) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at com.demo.iec.cloud.saga.hotel.HotelApplication.main(HotelApplication.java:15) ~[main/:na]
```

I can also confirm the dependent class does and is compiled into the expected folder

```
./saga/build/classes/java/main/com/demo/iec/cloud/saga/SagaCommandListener.class
```

This is a multi-module project with three spring boot projects

```
./hotel
./saga
./flight
```

Both hotel and flight depend on saga project and `SagaCommandLister` is part of the saga project.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when a spring boot project depends on another project with "also" spring boot plugin applied. Then the classes in the dependent project have this error. Not sure if this is to be treated as a bug. But in anycase removing the plugin declaration in `saga` solved it.